# Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server' failed — run manually if necessary And adb.exe has stopped working

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating my android studio, I am not capable of anymore running applications on my mobile device because of that error.I need this help.

Comment: I'm having the same problem after the installed update 2018-06-07

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your adb connection has hanged out. Open a console terminal and write `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`.

Comment: Thank you. I think problem is not adb start. i start the manually adb server and problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved:

I went toC:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk and deleted "platform-tools". Afterwards I installed a new "platform-tools": platform-tools_r27.0.1-windows" (I downloaded it here but you may find in another place http://mirrors.zzu.edu.cn/android/repository/platform-tools_r27.0.1-windows.zip)

That means that the new sdks might not be working for me because I am using "compileSdkVersion 27" in gradle

Comment: obviously its 3 years later and nothing is the same, however, this solution still works