# Android studio daemon not running starting now at tcp 5037 unable to run 'adb':null adb.exe start server failed run manually

Tags: android, android-studio

Not only is daemon not running but the local terminal also failed to start cmd.exe
Error starting winpty: agent timed out
I have already turned off the firewall and still getting these problems

Comment: give the adb exe path in user variable, see here https://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/

Comment: Tried it... Still isn't working

Comment: can you explain more what are you doing ?

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/vwQfL7xU688WAp7q7 this is the screen shot of the event log... I have turned off the firewall totally and have given the location of the adb path as user variable as shown in the link you provided... The terminal is not showing any problem though

Comment: I had deleted the first project do you think that could be the reason for the settings not loading?

Comment: the best thing is to uninstall everything and install android studio again, Thanks me a letter :)

Comment: Nothing else can be done?

Comment: try if you have a good internet connection.otherwise, we will find something else

Comment: Actually uninstalling and reinstalling everything is quite cumbersome and time taking so was trying to avoid it..

Comment: are you trying to run emulator right?

Comment: Yeah i guess... I just click on the run button

Comment: so do you make any emulator?

Comment: No i just made the design n tried to run it the emulator is installed already... Do I have to do smthn else to it?

Comment: yes, you have to create an emulator then you can run the app.

Comment: Could you please explain?

Comment: I have already created a virtual device in case that is what you mean..

Comment: aare baba, isse acha real device mai test kr lo, try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49148307/6925888

Comment: How to test it on a real device?? Some link?

Comment: I have restored the previous project due to which the settings problem was caused now only this problem is showing... https://photos.app.goo.gl/UyZLkcA9U2y66j2h8

Comment: how to run in real device https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app

Comment: need more :- https://www.tektutorialshub.com/android-studio/run-android-app-on-real-device/

Comment: Thank you ❤️Just this one last question... That adb error wouldn't case any problem in running the app??